# Seagate Drive Spins and Stops

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have a Seagate 2TB drive (Model: ST2000DM001 | FW: CC44) which was part of Seagate Backup Plus external drive. The drive spins and stops, the PC doesn't recognize it, I tried using it as an internal drive, the result is same.

I have recorded the sound, here it is:

https://soundcloud.com/aniruddh-joshi-193073480/hdd-sound

Is this issue fixable or I just lost everything in the drive?

Comment: It appears the drive is non-operational. Data recovery services might be able to transplant the platters to a new drive but not something you should attempt yourself (most applicable services won’t even attempt anything if the seal is broken)

Answer (score 2):

Examining the sound you provided, I conclude that the drive is physically broken, so only professional recovery services may be able to extract the data from it.

If this would occur while powered via an USB connection, there could of been a chance of the HDD having insufficient power, but since the drive was connected internally, there is no chance of that.